# I can't get a product attribute value

Tags: product, attributes, model, resource-model

I have a `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Item` object and I'm able to load a product model using the shipment item's sku (if I can get this attribute by just using the shipment item, all the better).

The loaded product model doesn't seem to contain the `size` attribute. When I `var_dump($prod->getData())` or `var_dump($prod)` there is nothing about its size. The attribute's code is `size`. It is set on the product I am loading, it is global, Dropdown type, not unique, required. How can I get a specific product attribute, in this case "size", from a model loaded by sku?

```
$prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
echo $prod->getSize();
echo $prod->getData('size');
```

Also, I would expect this to return a value of `57`. It is a dropdown type attribute. How can I get the value for this option_id? For example, I'd like to get the value `"small"`, not `57`. Btw, I see these values set for this particular sku in the database.

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9562720/550309) also

```
$pc = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('size', array('notnull' => 'true'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('size', array('neq' => ''))
    //->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('eq' => '100-0055-BLK-S'))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('size');
//$p = $pc->getFirstItem();
$usedAtts = array_unique($pc->getColumnValues('size'));
$attModel = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'size');
$usedAtts = $attModel->getSource()->getOptionText(implode(',', $usedAtts));
var_dump($usedAtts);
```

But `$usedAtts` is `false`.

**Update:** I tried the method in my first example, loading the product with `sku`, on a fresh install and it worked. I setup the size attribute just the same, except the new install has it in the 'default' attribute set, where the prior is a custom. I will try to look into those differences.. but in the meantime, anyone have an idea of why I can't get it in my prior install? I setup the products the same. In the prior, I can get the color attribute.. not sure why I can't get size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that when I was initializing Magento it was defaulting to the "default" store view (go figure). I needed to set it to the admin store view, then I'm able to get all the product info I needed.

```
require 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();

//admin store
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(0);
```

And this code now works just fine:

```
$prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
echo $prod->getSize() . ' - ' . $prod->getAttributeText('size');
```

Comment: Glad to see that `getAttributeText` is back to relive its glory days!

Comment: Default store view IS 0. What store view was yours defaulting to?

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question:

Thanks to some handy built-in methods you don't have to do any loading on your own:

- `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Item` provides `getOrderItem`
- `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item` provides `getProduct`

So, all you should have to do is this:

```
$product = $shipmentItem->getOrderItem()->getProduct();
```

If `size` is persisted to the order item, you can do:

```
$item = $shipmentItem->getOrderItem();
echo $item->getAttributeText('size');
```

Or, if you need to load the ID value from the product itself, you can get all of the product's selected ID values:

```
$size = $shipmentItem->getOrderItem()->getProduct()->getSize();
```

Comment: `$product = $shipmentItem->getOrderItem()->getProduct();` gives me the configurable product for the simple product that was ordered. And `size` is only set at the simple level. Check this out: `$prod = $si->getOrderItem()->getProduct(); 
echo $si->getSku() . ' | ' . $prod->getSku();`
That gives me `100-0055-BLK-S | 100-0055`, simple and configurable.

Comment: I'm guessing that the -S at the end of the simple sku is for size small?

Comment: Yes lol×Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.×

Comment: I think this is my best bet, if I could just get the simple. Something weird is happening. I added a new simple and config test product and linked them using default att set with this size att added, and I couldn't even load the product using `$prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', '1-1-BLK-S');` .. it returns false. I have a feeling the problems are related.

Answer (score 0):

Its easier to just pass this attribute to your quote and order. That way you can get it allover.

Add it to quote (in your config.xml from your extension)

```
<sales>
<quote>
    <item>
        <product_attributes>
            <custom_attribute />
        </product_attributes>
    </item>
</quote>
```

convert

```
<fieldsets>
    <sales_convert_quote_item>
        <custom_attribute>
            <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
        </custom_attribute>
    </sales_convert_quote_item>
    <sales_convert_order_item>
        <custom_attribute>
            <to_quote_item>*</to_quote_item>
        </custom_attribute>
    </sales_convert_order_item>
</fieldsets>
```

Copy the attribute to quote

```
    <events>
            <sales_quote_item_set_product>
                <observers>
                    <yourmodule>
                        <class>yourmodule/observer</class>
                        <method>setCustomAttribute</method>
                    </yourmodule>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_item_set_product>
   </events>
```

All these are under the global tag in your config.

Next you can copy your attribute to the quote trough the observer you just assigned the event to in your config:

```
public function setCustomAttribute(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $_item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
    $_product = $observer->getProduct();
    $_item->setCustomAttribute($_product->getCustomAttribute());
}
```

This way you won't have to load your product to get the value in your shippingmodel.

Comment: Is this still a valid way in Magento 1.9?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to these answers; if you need to get the attribute *value*, and you don't have the camel-case code available, you could use `getData()` on the product instead:

```
$product = $this->getProduct();
$attributeValue = $product->getData('attribute_code_here');
```